# How can we access/utilize mac build-in save to buffer feature?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, shortcut

Found this open source app where it helps capture gif (https://github.com/onmyway133/GifCapture), but it lacks one super useful feature, saving the captured result to the clipboard like the one in screenshot app.

Can use have apple script to achieve the same function, saving the captured result to clipboard?

Ps: there are some more updated and similar app (even more powerful) on github but I just found this one does the job. please share if you found an gif capture app that has saving to clipboard feature. please share.

Comment: @user3439894,  Thank you for the response. but I think you didn't understand the question or I misrepresented the question. Since I am trying to do the same for gif not image.

Comment: As **GifCapture** is written in **Swift** the developers could implement a copy to clipboard feature where it could then be pasted elsewhere.

Comment: based on your comment, it seems like we can can access to mac build-in save to clipboard feature?

Comment: You could raise an issue on GitHub for this (or develop it yourself and raise a pull request :-))